# How can I add 'repel = TRUE' in below code to make PCA more readable?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have used below code to create this plot, but it has too many overlaps, tough to read, I have also tried with `repel = TRUE`, but it also shows some error. My questions are (1) how can I add ggrepel in below code to make this graph more readable. (2), How can I make PCA vector rows bold.  [image]

```
ggplot() + 
      geom_hline(yintercept = 0, colour = "gray65") +
      geom_vline(xintercept = 0, colour = "gray65") +
      #geom_point(data = Root.Traits.pca12, aes(x = PC1, y = PC2), colour= "gray40", alpha = 0.5, size = 5) +
      geom_point(data = Root.Traits.pca12, aes(x = PC1, y = PC2, colour=Si), alpha = 0.8, size = 5, shape = 16)+
      
      #geom_point(data = arrows12, aes(x = PC1, y = PC2, fill=Nlevel), pch=21, colour=NA, alpha = .9, size = 3) +
      geom_segment(data = arrows12, aes(xend = 5*x2, yend = 5*y2), x=0, y=0, colour = "black") + 
      geom_text(data = arrows12, aes(x = 5*x2, 5*y2, label = corlabels),colour = "black", alpha = 1, size = 5) +
      coord_fixed(ratio = 1, xlim = c(-8, 6.6), ylim = c(-5, 7.5)) +
      scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(-7.5,-5,-2.5,0, 2.5, 5, 7.5))+
      scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(-5,-2.5,0, 2.5, 5))
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your Q1, replace `geom_text` with repulsive textual annotations `geom_text_repel()`. Your edited code will likely be `geom_text_repel(data = arrows12, aes(x = 5*x2, 5*y2, label = corlabels),colour = "black", alpha = 1, size = 5)` in `library(ggrepel)`.
For Q2, add `size=1`in `geom_segment()`. I hope it will work.